# How to handle VS2015 optimizer inconsistency?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, compiler-optimization

The following template function gets the number of records in a file.  It has worked correctly for years in Visual Studio (2005, 2012).  However in Visual Studio 2015, when optimized with “Maximize Speed /O2”, the division operation goes away and the incorrect value is returned.  (works in debug, not in release)

header file snippet:

```
template <class R, int N>
int MyClass<R,N>::GetCount() const
{
    return m_pPtr->GetFileSize() / sizeof(R) : 0;
}
```

Adding some logging in there seems to fix it, for example:

```
template <class R, int N>
int MyClass<R,N>::GetCount() const
{
    FILE *FP = fopen("test.log", "a+");
    fprintf(FP, "whatever");
    fclose(FP);
    return m_pPtr->GetFileSize() / sizeof(R) : 0;
}
```

Is there any way that this can be addressed in a reasonable way?

Comment: Get the latest update for VS2015. If that doesn't help file a bug report against VS and have it get fixed (looks severe enough to get fixed in a reasonable time).

Comment: I highly doubt this is a compiler bug. Show us how you call `GetCount` - the actual template parameters. Does `sizeof(R)` equal `1`?

Comment: Also, it doesn't matter which Visual Studio version you're using. What matters is the platform toolset (compiler) version (v120, v140...).